# jQuery "hasParent"

Tags: javascript, jquery

The JQuery "has" method effectively selects all elements where they have particular descendants.

I want to select elements based on the fact they have particular ancestors. I know about parent([selector]) and parents([selector]) but these select the parents and not the children with the parents.

So is there an ancestor equivalent of "has"?

**Note:** I already have the context of an element further down the hierarchy and I will be selecting based on this so I can't do a "top down" query.

**Update**

I've obviously explained myself really badly here, so I'll try and clarify:

```
<ul class="x">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="y">
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

I have a jQuery object that already consists of elements 2,3,4 and 5. I want to select those elements who have a parent with the class = x.

Hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

For a clean re-usable solution, consider extending the `jQuery.fn` object with a custom method used for determining the presence of a particular ancestor for any given element:

```
// Extend jQuery.fn with our new method
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn, {
    // Name of our method & one argument (the parent selector)
    within: function( pSelector ) {
        // Returns a subset of items using jQuery.filter
        return this.filter(function(){
            // Return truthy/falsey based on presence in parent
            return $(this).closest( pSelector ).length;
        });
    }
});
```

This results in a new method, `$.fn.within`, that we can use to filter our results:

```
$("li").within(".x").css("background", "red");
```

This selects all list items on the document, and then filters to only those that have `.x` as an ancestor. Because this uses jQuery internally, you could pass in a more complicated selector:

```
$("li").within(".x, .y").css("background", "red");
```

This will filter the collection to items that descend from either `.x` or `.y`, or both.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/6GMN5/

Comment: this is the "top down" approach I'm trying to avoid as I already have the element I want to start with. That's what I was trying to explain in my last note. Let's say you already have the second and third spans on that list in a jquery variable, how do you further filter that list?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, Chris, my perpended update addresses that.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the filter method. based on my edit, do you still think this would do it?

Comment: @Chris Simpson: Judging from your edits (and Jonathan's), I'd have to say yes.  Assuming you replace `.parent` with `.x` that is.

Comment: Use `return !!$(p).find(this).length;` to actually return `true` and `false`.

Comment: you should use parents() ......... if($("li").parents(".x").length == 1){ do something };

Answer (score 52):

`if ( $('.foo').parents('.parentSelector').length ) { // has parent }`

Comment: this would only really work for a single element. I want to select all the children with parents that match a certain criteria. But I've already got a jquery object to select from which is lower down the hierarchy (if this makes sense)

Comment: why will this only for a single element? If your selectors are correct, you should be fine. My code above reads "for _all_ elements with class 'foo', find their parents with class 'parentSelector' and return that jQuery collection". Maybe I'm missing something ... provide an example?

Comment: you are saying "if my element has got a matching parent, do something". I want to say "based on this list of elements, give me a list of elements that have parents matching a particular criteria"

Comment: +1 I like this solution best of all.  jQuery really should add `hasParent()` to their API, though.

Answer (score 36):

If I understand your question correctly, this would do:

```
$.fn.hasAncestor = function(a) {
    return this.filter(function() {
        return !!$(this).closest(a).length;
    });
};

$('.element').hasAncestor('.container').myAction();

<div class="container">
  <span>
    <strong class="element">strong</strong>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: since this value filters parents, rather than returning true/false I'd suggest renaming it `withAncestor` or `filterAncestor`. If I were reading code I would expect `hasAncestor` to return a boolean

Comment: ...although maybe I take that back since jQuery core has a 'has()' which behaves the same but for descendants. http://api.jquery.com/has/

Comment: On the other hand, `hasClass()` returns a boolean... Reminds me of one of the [two hard things in computer science](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)...

Comment: Strictly speaking, this implementation is not correct, as `closest()` will also match the currently selected element. That is, `$('.element').hasAncestor('.element');` will always return itself. The function you pass to `filter` should instead return `!!$(this).parent().closest(a).length`.

Answer (score 8):

```
$('body').hasParent('html') //true

$('div#myDiv').hasParent($('body')) //true
```

### #API:

```
// check if current element has parent element 'e' 
$.fn.hasParent = function (e) {
    return !!$(this).parents(e).length
}
```

Comment: Or at least it should be double exclamations "!!" to cast the result to a boolean.

Comment: @OytunTez  : Philosophy is related to the following JS rule : 
   - "0" is considered as "false" in logic predicate .

Comment: What I mean, is this return statement is reversing the result (probably while trying to cast the int to boolean)

Answer (score 4):

You can actually use `filter` directly (without a function calling `closest`) and it will have better performance.  Simply use a selector that matches elements contained within `.x`:

```
$("li").filter(".x *")
```

this also differs slightly from the `closest` solutions suggested by others in that it will not match if the element itself has the given class but only if it is **within** an element with that class.

If matching an element with the class is desired as well, this could be modified slightly:

```
$("li").filter(".x, .x *")
```

```js
$("li").filter(".x *").css("background", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="x"><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul>
<ul class="y"><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ul.myList > li > a
```

This selector selects only links that are direct children of list elements, which are
in turn direct children of  elements that have the class myList.

Answer (score 1):

```
object.each(function(){
    element = $(this);
    if(element.parent().hasClass("x")){
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

this will affect every item in your object that has parent .x

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is this:

```
// all children of a specific parent match
$('parentSelector').children();

// All children matching a specific pattern, one level deep
$('parentSelector > childSelector');
// or
// $('parentSelector').children('childSelector');

// All children matching a specific pattern, multiple levels deep
$('parentSelector childSelector');
// or
// $('parentSelector').find('childSelector');
```

or did you really need something more complicated than that?

Edit: If you already have an element, you can combine this with the parent() command, like so:

```
myElement.parents('parentSelector').find('childSelector'); // Will include self
```

Comment: added example html to the question that may explain things a little better

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but I'm leaving this here for future visitors looking for something similar;

There is a `$.contains(container, contained)` method which returns a boolean.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way to do it

```
$('.x').find('li')
```