# How to search for parent with either class - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, parent-child

I have two classes `reply` or `comment` in my html.

And have given a `delete` button for both of them. Now I want to `slideUp` the element with class `reply` or `comment` after success is returned.

What I want to do, is get the parent element in a var, and slide it up. But how do I search if the element has either parent with class `reply` or `comment`, and slide it up.

What looks best is using `hasParent` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389540/jquery-hasparent).

I will have to do that twice searching for both classes. Is there any better and efficient way to search the closest parent with class either `reply` or `comment` and `slideUp` the element.

What I am looking for is something like

```
var element = $(this).parents('.reply'||'.comment');
element.slideUp;
```

If not possible does hasParent work only with the parent or all ancestors?

Comment: The way I would go about it is select all `.reply .deletebutton` and `.comment .deletebutton` elements (that is every delete button that is in a comment or reply) and attach a handler to it that makes it's parent slide up. That way it only happens for replies and comments and doesn't require much (if any) checking if the parent actually is a comment/reply. This handler can even exist next to an other handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use comma

```
var element = $(this).parents('.reply, .comment');
```