# How to avoid the particular class from applying css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **My HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="finalparent">
<!--many parent divs here-->
<div id="1stparent">
     <div id="txt_blog_editor" class="box" style="width: 1097px;">
      <div class="abc anotherclass">

       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="abc"></div>
</body>
```

> **My Script**

```
 $('html').on('mouseover','.fr-bttn .fa-picture-o', function () {
        var pos = $(this).offset();
        console.log(pos.left+"||"+pos.top);
        var left_pos=(pos.left-15)+"px";
        var top_pos=(pos.top+35)+"px";
               $(".abc").css({position: "absolute", top: top_pos,  left: left_pos });
               $(".abc").show();
               $(".popup").show();
        });

    });
```

I want to apply the `left` and `top` to `abc` class which is without parent and not to the class which is under **`id="txt_blog_editor"`**

Comment: I think this might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389540/jquery-hasparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965816/what-jquery-selector-excludes-items-with-a-parent-that-matches-a-given-selector) here is a working snippet:

```js
jQuery.expr[':'].noparents = function(a,i,m){
    return jQuery(a).parents(m[3]).length < 1;
};


var elts = $(".abc").filter(":noparents(#txt_blog_editor)");
elts.css({ "background-color": "green" });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="finalparent">
<!--many parent divs here-->
<div id="1stparent">
     <div id="txt_blog_editor" class="box" style="width: 1097px;">
      <div class="abc anotherclass">
                ABC With Parent
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="abc">ABC WITHOUT Parent</div>
```

Basically, you create a new jQuery expression `:noparents` which returns elements not having *selector given* parents

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if .abc has a parent #txt_blog_editor http://jsfiddle.net/ugv2pxdw/4/

```
        $('html').on('mouseover','.fr-bttn .fa-picture-o', function () {
        var pos = $(this).offset();
        console.log(pos.left+"||"+pos.top);
        var left_pos=(pos.left-15)+"px";
        var top_pos=(pos.top+35)+"px";

         $('.abc').each(function(){
            if (!$(this).parents('#txt_blog_editor').length) {
                 $(this).css({position: "absolute",top: top_pos,  left: left_pos });
                           $(this).show();
                           $(".popup").show();
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: It works http://jsfiddle.net/ugv2pxdw/3/ You can't add a class to all the elements with class abc, only the target elements!!!

Comment: @Vaibs_Cool Here is a working example for your case http://jsfiddle.net/ugv2pxdw/4/ I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

If abc classes are only direct childs of body, why not using body > .abc as your selector?